# How to calculate percentage of values within one column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a table that gives me the percentage of No/Yes from the tech_support column. I am stuck with this query that gives me the raw data, but how do I calculate the percentages of values within one column. The resulting table from the query is below in the screenshot. Im using Postgres/PGadmin4.

```
select c.customer_id, age, l.state, s.tech_support
from customer as c
join location as l
on c.location_id = l.location_id
join services as s
on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
where age > 25 and age < 42 and state = 'NC'
```

[Table Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXMdG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation combining `SUM()` with `CASE`. For example, to get the ratio of 'Yes' over the total number of rows you can do:

```
with
q as (
  -- your query here
)
select
  1.0 * sum(case when tech_support = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) 
  /
  count(*)
from q
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to just get the ratio and not the rest of the data you can do:

```
select 1.0 * sum(case when tech_support = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end)
  / count()
from customer as c
join location as l
on c.location_id = l.location_id
join services as s
on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
where age > 25 and age < 42 and state = 'NC'
```

If you want to keep all the data "as is" and want to add the ratio as an extra column for all rows you can use `OVER()`. For example:

```
select c.customer_id, age, l.state, s.tech_support,
  1.0 * sum(case when tech_support = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) over()
  / count() over()
from customer as c
join location as l
on c.location_id = l.location_id
join services as s
on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
where age > 25 and age < 42 and state = 'NC'
```

Comment: this works, thanks. Is there another way to do this with a subquery so that the solution is only 1 query instead of breaking it up with a WITH and SELECT clause?

Comment: @blaxmyth See two other options.